# Agrupar array por nombre en Angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Tengo un Array con objetos como el siguiente:

```
[
  {"profile": "PRUEBA1","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
  {"profile": "PRUEBA3","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
  {"profile": "PRUEBA1","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
  {"profile": "PRUEBA3","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
  {"profile": "PRUEBA1","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
]
```

Entonces tengo un menú donde tengo 3 botones:

| PRUEBA1 | PRUEBA2 | PRUEBA3 |

Necesito que cuando haga click se muestren los objetos de PRUEBA1, cuando haga click en PRUEBA3 que es muestren los de PRUEBA3 y así sucesivamente... He agrupado en un array por nombre de perfil de la siguiente manera.

```
of(this.allMovements).pipe(
  mergeMap(res => res),
  groupBy(item => item.profile),
  mergeMap(obs => {
    return obs.pipe(
      toArray()
    )
  }), toArray()
).subscribe((p) => {
  this.finalgroups = p;
});
```

Esto me da una salida como la siguiente:

```
0:[
  {"profile": "PRUEBA1","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
  {"profile": "PRUEBA1","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
  {"profile": "PRUEBA1","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
]

1:[
  {"profile": "PRUEBA3","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
  {"profile": "PRUEBA3","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
]

2:[
  undefined
]
```

El problema de esto es que prueba 3 debería ir en el lugar 2 del array, por que en este caso no tengo datos con el nombre del perfil PRUEBA2

Un saludo y muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los observables que devuelve el `groupBy` tienen una propiedad `key` que contiene el valor de la clave usada para el agrupamiento. (en tu caso sería el string `PRUEBA1`, `PRUEBA2`,...).

Usando esa `key`, puedes devolver los resultados de cada grupo desde el `mergeMap` junto con su palabra clave.

```
mergeMap((obs$) =>
  obs$.pipe(
    toArray(),
    map((items) => ({ [obs$.key]: items }))  // <------
  )
),
```

Y posteriormente combinar todos los resultados en un único objeto con las parejas de claves<>resultados usando `reduce`

```
reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {})
```

El código completo quedaría así:

```
from(this.allMovements)
  .pipe(
    groupBy((item) => item.profile),
    mergeMap((obs$) =>
      obs$.pipe(
        toArray(),
        map((items) => ({ [obs$.key]: items }))
      )
    ),
    reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {})
  )
```

Y te devolvería un objeto con los resultados de la siguiente forma:

```
{
  PRUEBA1: [..., ... , ...]
  PRUEBA3: [..., ...]
}
```

un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```
//HTML
<button (click)="onClick('PRUEBA1')">
  Prueba 1
</button>
<button (click)="onClick('PRUEBA2')">
 Prueba 2
</button>
<button (click)="onClick('PRUEBA3')">
 Prueba 3
</button>

<p *ngFor="let move of data">{{ move | json }}</p>


//Typescript
export class AppComponent {
  data: Movement[] = [];
  movements: Movement[] = [
   {"profile": "PRUEBA1","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
   {"profile": "PRUEBA3","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
   {"profile": "PRUEBA1","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
   {"profile": "PRUEBA3","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
   {"profile": "PRUEBA1","benchmark": 0.01,"transferAmount": 3828604.78,"movement": 1},
  ];

  onClick(profile: string) {
    this.data = this.movements.filter((movement) => movement.profile === profile);
  }
}
```